# parameters sql query in find by sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to pass parameters sql query in find by sql

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The documentation explains it all. You do it like this, where author_id and start_date are the parameters passed in.

```
Post.find_by_sql ["SELECT title FROM posts WHERE author = ? AND created > ?", author_id, start_date]
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-find_by_sql

Comment: The fact that the parameterized SQL and the parameters themselves need to be put in an array was what helped me, here. I was trying to pass them to find_by_sql as 2 separate params.

Answer (score -2):

There are several different ways of doing this

one way would be what Brendan has proposed.

for others I'll take Brendan's example itself

2 -  `Post.find(:all, :conditions => "author=#{author_id} and created=#{start_date}")`

3 -  `Post.find_all_by_author_id_and_created(author_id, start_date)`

and If you are using rails 3 even you can build your query

http://m.onkey.org/2010/1/22/active-record-query-interface

cheers

sameera